# How to restrict weights in a range in keras

Tags: python, keras

i am using `keras` for a simple 3-layer `MLP`. I want to restrict weights of learned `MLP` in a range. for example after the model is fitted, all weights and biases be in range (-1, 1).
How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Constraint` for this.

There isn't a standard constraint for that, so we will need to create a custom one. The `unit_norm` is about "tensor norm", not about "single weight value".

```
from keras.constraints import Constraint
import keras.backend as K

class Between(Constraint):
    def __init__(self, min_value, max_value):
        self.min_value = min_value
        self.max_value = max_value

    def __call__(self, w):        
        return K.clip(w, self.min_value, self.max_value)

    def get_config(self):
        return {'min_value': self.min_value,
                'max_value': self.max_value}
```

In any layer that accepts a constraint there should be a `kernel_constraint` and a `bias_constraint` argument. Or some very similar names.

```
Dense(units, kernel_constraint=Between(), bias_constraint=Between())
```

### Loading models:

```
custom = {'Between':Between}
model = load_model(path, custom_objects = custom)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's work, but there is a problem in saving my model. After i save my model i can't load the model because `Between` is unknown. And another problem is my model not fitted good every time. do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The `constraints` module can be used to achieve this. This is applied to the weights(`kernel_constraint`) like this:

```
model.add(Dense(500, kernel_constraint=unit_norm()))
```

https://keras.io/constraints/#unitnorm

Comment: This answer is almost right, but this is about a "tensor norm". It uses an euclidean norm with square root of squares: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/constraints.py#L71